# How to make the "Split it!" button work in my app?

Tags: android

This is one of my first app projects and I am pretty excited! I cannot make the "split" button work (it has to divide the total by the number of people set in "people"). The first percentage buttons work fine, but not the last "split it!".

I am learning a lot and I love it!

xml.file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activiy_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    tools:context="com.example.dell.calculator.MainActivity"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/subtotal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Subtotal"
        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/itbms"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="ITBMS"
        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/diez"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="10%" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/quince"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="15%" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/veinte"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="20%" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.18"
        android:text="TOTAL"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Number of People"
        android:layout_weight="0.09" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/people"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/split"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Split It!" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/finalresult"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.55"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="EACH"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Mainactivity.java

```
    package com.example.dell.calculator;

import android.icu.text.NumberFormat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Locale;

import static com.example.dell.calculator.R.id.add;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView result, finalresult;
    EditText subtotal, itbms, people;
    Button diez, quince, veinte, split;

    float result_num, result_num2;
    int num1, num2, num3, num4;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        finalresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.finalresult);

        itbms = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.itbms);
        subtotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.subtotal);

        diez = (Button) findViewById(R.id.diez);
        quince = (Button) findViewById(R.id.quince);
        veinte = (Button) findViewById(R.id.veinte);

        diez.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                num1 = Integer.parseInt(subtotal.getText().toString());
                num2 = Integer.parseInt(itbms.getText().toString());
                result_num = (float) ((num1 + num2) * 1.10);
                result.setText(String.valueOf(result_num));
            }
        });

        quince.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                num1 = Integer.parseInt(subtotal.getText().toString());
                num2 = Integer.parseInt(itbms.getText().toString());
                result_num = (float) ((num1 + num2) * 1.15);
                result.setText(String.valueOf(result_num));
            }

        });

        veinte.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                num1 = Integer.parseInt(subtotal.getText().toString());
                num2 = Integer.parseInt(itbms.getText().toString());
                result_num = (float) ((num1 + num2) * 1.20);
                result.setText(String.valueOf(result_num));
            }

        });


        split.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                num4 = (int) result_num;
                num3 = Integer.parseInt(people.getText().toString());
                result_num2 = (float) num4 / num3;
                finalresult.setText(String.valueOf(result_num2));

            }

        });


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to obtain the button view reference:

Change this:

```
        diez = (Button) findViewById(R.id.diez);
        quince = (Button) findViewById(R.id.quince);
        veinte = (Button) findViewById(R.id.veinte);
```

for this:

```
     diez = (Button) findViewById(R.id.diez);
     quince = (Button) findViewById(R.id.quince);
     veinte = (Button) findViewById(R.id.veinte);
     split = (Button) findViewById(R.id.split);
```

This kind of errors can be detected by reading the app log. I am sure that a `NullPointerException` ocurrs caused by the invokation of `split.setOnClickListener` (split was `null`).

Comment: I included the button view reference in the setOnClickListener of the split button, and not only it does not work, but the emulator does not open the app. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Did you add this split = (Button) findViewById(R.id.split);? you did this for the others buttons

Comment: Where should I add that code? I include it for every button with the correspondent id into the setOnClick but is not working. :(

Comment: Pablo thank you. I solved it! In addition, the two first EditText that I use, so you can input the values, they do not accept and operate with decimal numbers. I already set the input type to decimal number but itdoes not work. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is totally normal, for beginners.I would recommend you to Declare and initialize View Objects(Button,TextView..etc)
simultaneously.

```
Button split = (Button) findViewById(R.id.split);
```

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: My answer was a suggestion so as to avoid such mistakes.Refer Mr.Pablo's answer.Also I would suggest you to brush up some JAVA Basics.[JAVA basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html).And refer android docs[Android guide](https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html).